# Keras prediction after the model is trained

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, prediction

I have trained a Keras model and saved the model and the weights to two separate files. My training data and validation data are divided into two classes like this:

```python
training_data/
    positive/
    negative
validation_data/
    positive/
    negative/
```

Both training data directories contain 900k samples each, the validation data directories contain 20k samples each. All the samples are 43x43px.

My model and the learning process are defined like this:

```python
def get_model(img_width, img_height):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    return model

model = get_model(43, 43)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save(os.path.join('model.h5'))
model.save_weights(os.path.join('weights.h5'))
save_model_info(params)
```

The training process for 20 epochs, batch size of 1024, 1.800.000 training samples, and 40.000 validation samples took about 5 hours. The `history` object is here because I am also saving the accuracy and learning graphs.

Now, I am trying to make this model predict which of trained two classed is present in given testing sample. So, I create the model, load the weights and trying to run the prediction.

```python
model = get_model(43, 43)
model.load_weights(args.weights_file)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

result = []
files = os.listdir(input_dir)
for file in files:
    image = load_img(file)
    image = np.asarray(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    result.append(model.predict(image))

print(result)
```

It is working, but not the way I would like it to. The output is like this:

```python
[array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

And here is my question. I need it for each given file to make prediction like

```python
{'negative': 0.925, 'positive': 0.0725}
```

The format is not relevant here. My point is, how to get the probability for each class that has been trained? I think I tried to use all the model prediction methods, but none of them gave me what I need. Am I doing something wrong in the code or it needs to be done somehow different?

Comment: 1) you are offering a bunch of irrelevant info (batch size, size of your datasets etc) and you do not provide the most basic - what exactly does your model do? Binary classification or something else? 2) forget the `for file in files` and file appends etc (code here is supposed to be **minimal**), and please post the result of a **single** `model.predict()` command

Comment: @desertnaut This is binary classification (positive/negative), sorry for not saying that, and I posted the list of `predict` results, single result would be `array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32)`

Comment: There are a a few possible causes. Old versions of Keras IIRC distinguished predict_proba (to predict probabilities) and predict (for class ie 0/1 prediction). New versions use predict/predict_classes, but maybe you are using an old version. So try predict_proba instead of predict. Next, try running just a one epoch on a small batch to check you are not overtraining somehow and your network isn't just converging on zero. Finally it could be that you have the wrong kind of output, but from a quick look that looks ok for binary classification. Lmk how you geton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to offer a *methodology*, both for tracking down the root cause of your issue, and for making it easier for respondents here at SO to help you...

First, as I said in my comment, code in SO is supposed to be [**minimal**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e just enough to reproduce the issue; since we don't have access to your data, there is no point at all to include details like your `training_generator`, `validation_generator`, directory structure, or [...], which are useless for respondents and just distract attention (they could be useful only in case you were using a publicly available dataset, like MNIST or CIFAR):

> **Minimal**
>
> The more code there is to go through, the **less likely people can find
>   your problem**.

Arguably, the same principle holds also for the *text* in the question...

Second, try to predict some hand-picked samples that you *know* are *positive* (I assume that 0's are your negatives), i.e. that should give outputs close to 1; for all I know, with the info you have provided, it may be the case that there is nothing wrong, and simply the (few) test samples you have tried all happen to give probability 0 (negative) - maybe improbable, but not impossible, and you'd better check it explicitly.

Clarifying on the last point: since your last layer has a single node, your output will be a *single* number in [0,1], which usually is to be taken as the probability `p` for one of your classes (the probability for the other one being simply `1-p` in binary classification); so, at least the *format* of your output is no strange at all.

Third, try to make some predictions *before saving your model*, as there have been several issues reported with model saving & loading (google it), and compare them with the same predictions from a loaded model; if there is a discrepancy, you have narrowed significantly your search for the cause.

Hope this helps; hopefully, *if* there is indeed something wrong, following these steps will assist you either to solve the issue yourself, or to narrow it to a specific point about which you can open a new, more focused question here. In such a case, following the SO guidelines on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will significantly raise the chances that you get a useful answer from someone...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not want to give you too much of the code, but I just started to learn keras (and machine learning) and I did not know which parts of the code are important, I will remember that. I will to do as you said and let you know if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue and it is working. The problem was that I added the `rescale` parameter in the ImageGenerator while training the model:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2)
```

And I did not add this while running predictions:

```
for file in files:
    image = load_img(file)
    image = np.asarray(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    result.append(model.predict(image))
```

I change this line

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

And now it looks like this

```
img = np.expand_dims(img / 255, axis=0)
```

I also updated loading the model, changed there lines (but just for prediction, not the training):

```
model = get_model(43, 43)
model.load_weights(args.weights_file)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

into this:

```
model = load_model(args.model_file)
```

I run the prediction with all my samples and fill a numpy array with the results, then change that array to image and it's working. Thank you all for help and sorry again for the amount of code.